# macOS Seirra randomly boots me to login screen while I'm working

Tags: macos, login-screen

This has happened a few times over the years but more frequently. Lately, I'll be using my 13" Macbook Air (2014) and for no reason I can figure out, the entire system will freeze, the screen will go black, and then I will be logged off and returned to the login screen. I have no warning this is happening and no way to stop it. After logging in again all the applications have been closed applications and any unsaved work is lost. I also have no way to MAKE it happen.

Pretty sure this isn't Security and Privacy issue as it happens while I'm browsing or watching a video or sometimes mid-keystroke. I also don't think its a overloaded or taxed by excessive RAM demands by the programs in use, just basic browser, chat, WP and video.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything of interest in `/var/log/system.log` Just before the reboot?

Comment: How would I check that? Still a newb

Comment: Open terminal app & type: `tail -n 10 /var/log/system.log`

Comment: Open Console.app as an admin user to access log files

Comment: @Fayaz After a reboot the last ten lines will contain messages from the boot process, not the crash

Comment: Try creating a new account, log into that one and use that exclusively. If it never does the sudden lockout it was something (corrupt file, or similar) specific to that particular user account. I would then back up only the necessary documents/settings in the old profile and copy them to the new one.

Comment: @nohillside console is not much use as it only shoes what happens after it has started